# React quiz app with Redux, React Router

Tags: react.js, redux

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quiz-kb1xb

I was wondering what could be improved upon it. I am looking at how it's using Redux and how it's also using hooks and I don't really see anything wrong with it, but I am wondering if it could be improved upon.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';



class ResultTile extends Component {


    isCorrect(options, answers, index) {
        let i
        options.map((value, index1) => {
            if (value.isAnswer === true)
                i = index1
            return null
        })
        if (options[i].name === answers[index]) return true
        else return false
    }

    getAnswer(options) {
        let answer
        options.map((val, index) => {
            if (val.isAnswer === true) {
                answer = options[index].name
            }
            return null
        })

        return answer
    }


    render() {
        let key = 0

        return (
            this.props.questions.map((question, index) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        key={question.id - 1000}
                        className={this.isCorrect(question.options, this.props.answers, index) ? "alert alert-success mx-auto px-4 py-1 w-100 " : "alert alert-danger mx-auto px-4 py-1  w-100"}
                        role="alert">
                        <p className="font-weight-bold" > <strong> Q{question.id - 1000}.</strong> {question.name} </p>
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <form className=" ">
                                    {question.options.map((option) => {
                                        return <div
                                            key={key++}
                                            className="form-check">
                                            <input
                                                className="form-check-input key"
                                                type="radio"
                                                checked={option.name === this.props.answers[index]}
                                                disabled />
                                            <label
                                                className="form-check-label">
                                                {option.name}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    })
                                    }
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="alert alert-dark p-1 mt-3 mb-2 w-100" role="alert">
                            Right answer is : <strong>{this.getAnswer(question.options)}</strong>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                )
            }
            )
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        answers: state.answers,
        questions: state.questions

    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        updateBonus: () => dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_BONUS", value: 100 }),
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ResultTile);
```

You can check the whole app, or just this component in particular, because it's one of the bigger components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways that you can use newer syntaxes to make this cleaner:

- Function component instead of class component.
- Replace `connect` with react-redux hooks.
- Create your actions with redux-toolkit.
- Write better loops with specific array methods.

---

For that last point about array methods, here's a good example:

```
getAnswer(options) {
    let answer
    options.map((val, index) => {
        if (val.isAnswer === true) {
            answer = options[index].name
        }
        return null
    })

    return answer
}
```

We could rewrite that with `.find()` to find the correct answer.  Your current use of `.map()` doesn't make any sense because you aren't using the mapped array.  You are using it like a `forEach()`.  But `find()` is more appropriate to this situation.

```
getAnswer(options) {
    // Find the first option with a true value of `isAnswer`.
    const correctOption = options.find(option => option.isAnswer);
    // Return its name
    return correctOption?.name;
}
```

Which could easily be a one-liner:

```
const getAnswer = (options) => options.find(option => option.isAnswer)?.name;
```

But I would kill both that function and your overly-complex `isCorrect` function and evaluate them inside of your loop:

```
{questions.map((question, index) => {
    const selectedAnswer = answers[index];
    const correctAnswer = question.options.find(option => option.isAnswer)?.name;
    const isCorrect = selectedAnswer === correctAnswer;
```

---

You have some other functions that aren't entirely necessary, for example:

```
isAnswered = (index, answers) => {
   if (answers[index]) {
       return true
   }
   return false
}
```

This is the same as simply checking the boolean value of `answers[index]` with `!!answers[index]`.

You could simplify it to a one-liner:

```
isAnswered = (index, answers) => !!answers[index]
```

But it's just as easy to write the `!!answers[index]` directly instead of calling `isAnswered(index, answer)`.

---

Here's how you can rewrite your reducer with Redux Toolkit:

```
import questions from "./questions";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  questions: questions,

  counter: 0,

  answers: []
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "quiz",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    jumpToFirst: (state) => {
      state.counter = 0;
    },
    jumpToLast: (state) => {
      state.counter = state.questions.length - 1;
    },
    jumpToQuestion: (state, action) => {
      state.counter = action.payload;
    },
    prev: (state) => {
      state.counter--;
    },
    next: (state) => {
      state.counter++;
    },
    updateAnswer: (state, action) => {
      const { index, answer } = action;
      state.answers[index] = answer;
    }
  }
});

export default slice.reducer;

export const {
  jumpToFirst,
  jumpToLast,
  jumpToQuestion,
  prev,
  next,
  updateAnswer
} = slice.actions;
```

We now have action creator functions so that you can dispatch `prev()` instead of `{type: "PREV"}`.  This ensures that your type names are always correct.

---

But we can slim down that reducer a lot because you might be suffering from a bit of action-overload.  Though there's nothing *wrong* with these actions, you don't *need* `jumpToFirst`, `jumpToLast`, `prev`, or `next` as these are all specific instances of `jumpToQuestion`.  You really only need `jumpToQuestion` and `updateAnswer`.

Here's how the `QuestionNavigation` component might look with a single action type, using a `createButton` helper function to cut back on the repetitiveness of the four buttons.  Now if you want to change the button styling it's just one place instead of four.

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { jumpToQuestion } from "../redux/reducer";

export default function QuestionNavigation() {
  const lastIndex = useSelector((state) => state.questions.length - 1);
  const currentIndex = useSelector((state) => state.counter);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const isFirst = currentIndex === 0;
  const isLast = currentIndex === lastIndex;

  const createButton = (text, index, disabled) => {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => dispatch(jumpToQuestion(index))}
        className="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2"
        disabled={disabled}
      >
        {text}
      </button>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-2">
      <hr />
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        {createButton("First", 0, isFirst)}
        {createButton("Prev", currentIndex - 1, isFirst)}
        {createButton("Next", currentIndex + 1, isLast)}
        {createButton("Last", lastIndex, isLast)}
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Here's my revised version of the `ResultTile`:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function ResultTile() {
  const questions = useSelector((state) => state.questions);

  const answers = useSelector((state) => state.answers);

  return (
    <>
      {questions.map((question, index) => {
        const selectedAnswer = answers[index];
        const correctAnswer = question.options.find((option) => option.isAnswer)?.name;
        const isCorrect = selectedAnswer === correctAnswer;
        return (
          <div
            key={question.id}
            className={
              "alert mx-auto px-4 py-1 w-100 " +
              (isCorrect ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger")
            }
            role="alert"
          >
            <p className="font-weight-bold">
              <strong> Q{question.id - 1000}.</strong> {question.name}
            </p>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <form className=" ">
                  {question.options.map((option) => (
                    <div key={option.name} className="form-check">
                      <input
                        className="form-check-input key"
                        type="radio"
                        checked={option.name === selectedAnswer}
                        disabled
                      />
                      <label className="form-check-label">{option.name}</label>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="alert alert-dark p-1 mt-3 mb-2 w-100" role="alert">
              Right answer is: <strong>{correctAnswer}</strong>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

[Complete CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quiz-forked-t1ih1?file=/src/component/questionTile.js)